# For i loop, calling different dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm new to loops and I have a problem with calling variable from i'th data frame.

I'm able to call each data frame correctly, but when I should call a specified variable inside each data frame problems come:

Example:

```
for (i in 1:15) {
    assign(
      paste("model", i, sep = ""), 
    (lm(response ~ variable, data = eval(parse(text = paste("data", i, sep = "")))))
    )
    plot(data[i]$response, predict.lm(eval(parse(text = paste("model", i, sep = ""))))) #plot obs vs preds
}
```

Here I'm doing a simple one variable linear model 15 times, which works just fine.  Problems come when I try to plot the results. How should I call `data[i]` response?

Comment: Why are you using `assign` and `eval`? You can use a list to store all your datasets.

Comment: If you are a beginner and you find yourself using `assign`, `eval` or `parse`, there is an extremely high probability that there is a much better way to do this in R. As @VincentZoonekynd pointed out, use a list.

Comment: Do you have any links to this kind of looping structures? I've tried to find some, but I'm not sure if they are what I'm looking for. Each dataset (n=15) has 68 variables and 284 obs. I'd also like to change the variable I call. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use `lapply` for the loop.

Comment: `data[i]` is not the same as an object named "data<i>" where the <i> is meant to be a digit or sequence of digits,

Answer (score 3):

Let's say there are multiple dataframes with names: data1 ...data15 and that there are no other data-objects that begin with the letters: d,a,t,a. Lets also assume that in each of those dataframes are columns named 'response' and 'variable'. The this would gather the dataframes into a list and draw separate plots for the linear regression lines.

```
dlist <- lapply ( ls(patt='^data'), get)
lapply(dlist, function(df) 
                 plot(NA, xlim=range(df$variable), ylim=range(df$response)
                 abline( coef( lm(response ~ variable, data=df) ) )
         )
```

If you wanted to name the dataframes in that list, you could use your paste code to supply names:

```
names(dlist) <- paste("data", i, sep = "")
```

There are many other assignments you could make in the context of this loop, but you would need to describe the desired results better than with failed efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's modified code that should work. It does one variable lm-model and calculates correlation of predicted and observed values and stores it into an empty matrix. It also plots these values.
Thanks Thomas for help.

```
par(mfrow=c(4,5))
results.matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 20, ncol = 2)
colnames(results.matrix) <- c("Subset","Correlation")

for (i in 1:length(datalist)) {
    model <- lm(response ~ variable, data = datalist[[i]])
    pred <- predict.lm(model)
    cor <- (cor.test(pred, datalist[[i]]$response))
    plot(pred, datalist[[i]]$response, xlab="pred", ylab="obs")
    results.matrix[i, 1] <- i
    results.matrix[i, 2] <- cor$estimate
}
```

Comment: `for (i in datalist)` should be `for (i in 1:length(datalist))`.

Comment: `model <- lm(response ~ variable, data = i)` should be `model <- lm(response ~ variable, data = datalist[[i]])`.

Comment: `cor <- (cor.test(pred, i$response)` should be `cor <- (cor.test(pred, datalist[[i]]$response)`.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include those changes so that it's a working solution.